# Problems with setvisibility for button on RelativeLayout Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, button

Hy.... I'm making a simple project on eclipse. I'm using relative layout as shown below :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:gravity="center"   
    tools:context=".ProfileActivity" 
    >

<Button 
        android:id="@+id/Prof_edit_btn"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Prof_LL"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"            
        android:text="Edit"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        />

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_below="@+id/Prof_LL"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

        >
    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/Prof_save_btn"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Prof_LL"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"            
        android:text="save"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:clickable="false"
        />
    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/Prof_batal_btn"            
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Batal"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp"            
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:clickable="false"
        />
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

In the main activity, I've made a simple onClicklistener for Edit and Save button as shown below :

```
mEdit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Prof_edit_btn);
mEdit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {               
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub                  
                    mBatal.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    mBatal.setClickable(true);
                    mSave.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    mSave.setClickable(true);
                    mEdit.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);                    
            }
        });

mSave = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Prof_save_btn);
mSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {               
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                mEdit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);  
                mBatal.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                mSave.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data Anda berhasil disimpan", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                  
            }
        });
```

Well... As we can see from my layout xml, only EDIT button will be visible on the start, then SAVE and BATAL button will be visible when EDIT is clicked by user according to the code program within setonclick listener of EDIT button. And as soon as EDIT button is clicked it will be invisible.... The problems here are WHen I clicked EDIT button, only SAVE button will be visible and BATAL button will be visible when SAVE button is clicked, another problem that I'm facing now is EDIT button is not invisible at all when I click it.... So.. anyone can help me with this problem please...??? :'(

Thanks in advance....

Comment: where is mBatal buttons find ID?

Comment: I still didn't add it yet ... :-)

Comment: But... That button will be having almost the same clicklistener with mSave button... :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Naaah... I found my own solution... Just set the visibility of SAVE btn and BATAL btn to GONE... And it's all done.... :-)

```
<Button 
            android:id="@+id/Prof_save_btn"
            android:layout_below="@+id/Prof_LL"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"            
            android:text="save"
            android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:visibility="gone"<-----------=
            android:clickable="false"
            />
        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/Prof_batal_btn"            
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="Batal"
            android:layout_marginTop="17dp"            
            android:visibility="gone"<-----------=
            android:clickable="false"
            />
```

Comment: Ooowh... Yeaah... I forgot to remove that...hehehe.. Thanks haint... :-)